# Can I use AppCode while others use Xcode in my team?

Tags: ios, xcode, appcode

In my company we are 5 and all of us use Xcode. I would like try AppCode.
Apart from adding .idea to my ignore git list, is there anything else I should do? Is it possible to have conflicts or incompatibilities if some people use Xcode and others use AppCode? Thanks.

Comment: I've used Xcode with another developer who used AppCode, and even if I can't answer your question, I can tell you this with certainty : It's a good idea to switch to AppCode, it'll be faster and easier to use it, and any "special setup" required is clearly worth the pain, if there is any (which I don't know).
I suggest you have a look on the appcode website, if there was somethign special, I'm sure they'd mention it

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any inherent conflicts developing in a mixed-IDE environment--I've worked on projects where teammates are using AppCode while I use Xcode, and everything Just Works™. As you say, keep the `.gitignore` file up to date, and as always, be prepared for conflicts in your `project.pbxproj` file--that's a problem regardless of which IDE you're using.

Also be aware that you'll have to drop back to Xcode for some tasks that AppCode doesn't support, like Interface Builder, but if you're OK with that, it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 4):

In short - yes, you can use AppCode in your situation, no, you should not encounter conflicts or incompatibilities. AppCode is frequently used in teams where some of developers use Xcode, some use AppCode. Note, that there are some areas when you will need to switch to the Xcode - for example, editing UI interface files or CoreData objects. But when you edit code files, add it to the Xcode project etc - these changes will be synced across both IDEs.

I suggest you to look through the Quick Start Guide [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/objc/2016.1/quick-start-guide.html) cause AppCode interface comes from the Intellij Platform and sometimes for Xcode users it's a bit "unusual", so after reading this article it will be easier for you to understand, where to find particular view or action. In addition I suggest to read [these articles](http://blog.jetbrains.com/objc/tag/5shortcuts/) about some shortcuts that are really helpful for everyday use and look through the [videos](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/documentation/) on our site.